# Shortcut to switch between different spreadsheet in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

Is there a keyboard-shortcut to switch between different sheet in MS-excel?

Comment: You now have answers for both! :-)

Comment: Please do a little research before asking. This is also mentioned in the official list of keyboard shortcuts (actually the first two…): http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-2010-HP010342494.aspx

Comment: I will, sorry for this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, since Excel (2010 and 2013, not sure about previous versions) uses workbook and worksheets as it's terminology.

I assume when you say spreadsheet, you mean these:

[image]

The easiest way to cycle through **worksheets** is to press

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>page down</kbd>

or

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Page up</kbd>

[More shortcuts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-2010-HP010342494.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

**In Excel 2003**, the Window menu is opened with Alt-W, so switching between spreadsheets (windows) is done using:

```
Alt-W <number>
```

where <number> is the number of the window as shown in the Window menu. Note that it's necessary to release Alt before pressing the number.

**In Excel 2007, Excel 2010 and Excel 2013**, the ribbon bar's View tab is opened with Alt-W, after which it is possible to type W followed by the window number to switch windows:

```
Alt-W W <number>
```

e.g.

```
Alt-W W 1
```

or

```
Alt-W W 2
```